# How to create new devise user using foreign controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, devise

I have been trying this since hours, but to no avail, so, finally seeking you guys for help.

> Scenario

I have two devise models, viz College and Manager. They both work fine, but what I want to achieve is that College should be able to create or delete a Manager. For this, I created a Codashboard controller#view, which is only accessible when College is signed in. This controller#view pair has a form for submitting Manager email and password and commiting to database.

> Problem

Whenever I Submit my form, i don't get any error, but the changes are not committed to the database.

> Details

Extract from Terminal

```
Started POST "/codashboard" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-14 04:59:41 +0530
Processing by CodashboardController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"P85GD7Wnt1RYNDgxxMxrSH6tUzW/PUBvqTXs8lYHY+HkvRXnq3s/IQL50SyMeDI1xXlalztTMbTZDNcPsXuckw==", "manager"=>{"email"=>"manager11@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/codashboard
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Corresponding view

```
<%= form_for @addmanager, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
    <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

    <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Corresponding Controller

```
class CodashboardController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if college_signed_in?
        @managers = College.find_by_id(current_college.id).managers
        @addmanager = Manager.create(params[:addmanager])
    end
  end

  def new
    @addmanager = Manager.new
  end

  def create
    Manager.create(params[:addmanager])
    redirect_to codashboard_index_path
  end

  def addmanager
    @addmanager = Manager.new(:email => "manager8@gmail.com", :password => "qwertyuiop")
    @addmanager.save
    redirect_to codashboard_index_path
  end
end
```

Note: I tried using default devise form but it always signs_in after creation of new user which I don't want.

Note2: The method addmanager works fine and adds an entry in database whenever invoked. So, there is no problem with my model.

Please suggest what might be the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect a validation error, you don't see any error because you are redirecting in both a failed and successful validation, two options here:

Quick and dirty way, change `Manager.create` to `Manager.create!` this will throw an error if the validation fails.

Do it nice, and re-render the form on a validation failure with error messages:

```
class CodashboardController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @addmanager = Manager.new(addmanager_params)

    if @addmanager.save
      redirect_to codashboard_index_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def addmanager_params
    require(:addmanager).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end 
end
```

I also added strong params to ensure that only permitted attributes can be set.

**Update:**

The real error is, that Rails infers the attribute key from the model passed to it (i.e `@addmanager.class` which is `Manager`), so your response in your log shows, its keyed as "manager":

```
"manager"=>{"email"=>"manager11@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

But you expect it to be keyed as "addmanager", like this:

```
"addmanager"=>{"email"=>"manager11@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

To enforce this, you can change the `form_for` form builder to use an alias using the `as:` option:

```
<%= form_for @addmanager, as: :addmanager, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
```

Comment: Did that, the result:

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in CodashboardController#create 


Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank
  def create
   Manager.create!(params[:addmanager])
   redirect_to codashboard_index_path
  end

Comment: okay, just double checked have a close look at your log, it says `manager: { email: ...., password: ..., ....}` but you expect it to be `addmanager: { email: ...., password: ...., ... }`

Comment: I guess not, @addmanager is user defined variable. Manager is the model I generated using devise

Comment: `form_for` will infer the key for the attributes from `@addmanager.class` which is `Manager`.

Comment: I tried what you said, which gave me
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in CodashboardController#create

Comment: Referring last part of http://jonathanyeong.com/saving-form-model-rails/, I can say that's a progress :)

Comment: the `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` is caused by not explicitly permitting certain parameters, check the `addmanager_params` method in my example. Adapt the naming there as needed, and make sure you use `Manager.new(addmanager_params)`.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaand we did it. 
Wholhearted thanks to sled :) I owe you a coffee.

Answer (score 0):

I recently learned that Devise is only AUTHENTICATION, but doesn't include AUTHORIZATION. The College Model is not authorized to create other Devise models. I suggest using an authorization gem such as [CanCanCan](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/auth/authorization.html).

Hope that helps!

Comment: this should not matter, since he's working directly on the database models in the controller, which has full control.

Comment: Oh - I was under the impression that you can't create other users when logged in, and since both models are Devise, this would be the limitation.